# Understanding Cursive Script Irish Baptismal Reg Entry March 1846, accessed via RC Parish Records National Library Ireland

Tags: baptism-records

Request assistance in understanding Cursive writing for March 1846 Baptismal Reg Ireland RC Parish - cannot make out surname after Catherine in reg at the baptism of Rose McGauran.

[image]

Source Killeshandra | Microfilm 05346 / 01 /  diocese Kilmore, county Cavan, Ireland

https://registers.nli.ie/registers/vtls000634865#page/10/mode/1up [image]

Comment: To enable potential answerers to View more of the document can you provide a link or links to where it can be viewed?

Comment: Link to reg added and 2 page view - parish Killeshandra, diocese Kilmore, county Cavan, Ireland

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is Catherine Dignan or possibly its variant Degnan. The same surname is in the next line written more clearly for Bridget Dignan. There is a 1b written at the end of the name which you have to ignore to see the name clearly.

Edit: As AndyW points out in the comments, it is probably 2'6 written at the end of the line, not 1b.

Comment: I'm not sure it's "1b" at the end of the line. Comparing to other lines, it might be "1'6" or "2'6", which I'd guess was the amount paid for the baptism in shillings and pence.

Comment: Yes, that makes more sense. Looking at it with that in mind it does look more like 2'6.

Comment: The symbols 's' for shilling and 'd' for pence derive from the Latin solidus and denarius used in the Middle Ages.
2 farthings = 1 halfpenny
2 halfpence = 1 penny (1d)
3 pence = 1 thruppence (3d)
6 pence = 1 sixpence (a 'tanner') (6d)
12 pence = 1 shilling (a bob) (1s)
2 shillings = 1 florin ( a 'two bob bit') (2s)
2 shillings and 6 pence = 1 half crown (2s 6d)
5 shillings = 1 Crown (5s)

Comment: You had to pay for a baptism in Ireland?? Will wonders never cease....

Comment: @JPmiaou  Yes, but amortize that cost over an eternity in heaven,  and it looks remarkably good value... :)

Comment: Yes but my worry is that my ancestors paid in Irish coinage and  the Irish pound continued to exist and was not replaced by sterling until January 1826. The conversion rate had long been 13 Irish pounds to 12 pounds sterling. The Irish pound was readopted in 1928, six years after the Anglo-Irish Treaty restored Irish independence. Their money has gone thru so many changes and then decimilization and then finally the Euro...hope their eternity is covered where ever they are....would not look good if evicted for non payment!

Comment: @JPmiaou Not just in Ireland. See https://www.familysearch.org/wiki/en/History_of_Parish_Registers_in_England

Comment: Interesting Jan, the Stamp Duties Act 1783 Great Britain was passed to pay for the American War of Independance in that all baptism, marriage and burial entries in each parish register were subject to a tax of 3d with ministers permitted to collect the duty and to keep 10% of this fee as compensation. Moreover a refusal to pay carried a fine of five pounds, wonder how often this was acted on - the number of supposed poor people within a parish increased above normal during these years until the act was finally repealed in 1794. Need to investigate more re this and effect on Irish baptisms.